# Kotlin, memory saving

Tags: kotlin, memory, out-of-memory

I'm working on Splay Tree. I have a lot of command input (add, delete and etc), Hence the output is also huge (32MB of text in a txt file)

I have a memory problem, I am currently using two MultitableList and I have 200 MB of virtual memory (128 MB is needed for the project)
I run on Linux with the command:

```
$ kotlinc Kotlin.kt -include-runtime -d outPutFile.jar
$ /usr/bin/time -v java -jar outPutFile.jar
```

result:  Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 249732 (With each launch different sizes but about 200)

how can i reduce the size?  I need to change the size after each cycle

```
class SplayTree {
    var ROOT: Node? = null

    class Node(val key: Long, var value: String?) {
        var _parent: SplayTree.Node? = null
        var _RightChild: SplayTree.Node? = null
        var _LeftChild: SplayTree.Node? = null

        ...  there is a code here ...
        // for output
        override fun toString(): String {
            if (_parent == null) {
                return "[${key} ${value}]"
            } else {
                return "[${key} ${value} ${_parent!!.key}]"
            }
        }
    }

  ...  there is a code here ...
 override fun toString(): String {
        if (ROOT == null) {
            return "_"
        }

        println(ROOT)

        var NOWqueueList: List<Node?> = listOf(ROOT)
        var BABYqueue: MutableList<Node?> = MutableList(0) { null }

        //var NOWqueueList = Array<Node?>(1, {ROOT})         // Array
        //var BABYqueue = Array<Node?>(1, {null})            // Array

        //var n = 1    // Array
        for (h in 1 until height(ROOT)) {

            // for Array
            //var pos = -1
            //n *= 2
            //BABYqueue = Array<Node?>(n, {null}) //for future line
            for (ROOTList in NOWqueueList) {

                //pos++           // Array
                if ( ROOTList != null){
                    //left
                    if (ROOTList.haveLeftBaby()) {
                        //BABYqueue[pos] = ROOTList._LeftChild       // Array
                        BABYqueue.add(ROOTList._LeftChild)
                        print(ROOTList._LeftChild.toString())
                        print(" ")
                    } else {
                        //BABYqueue[pos] = null          // Array
                        BABYqueue.add(null)
                        print("_ ")
                    }
                    //pos++           // Array
                    //right
                    if (ROOTList.haveRightBaby()) {
                        //BABYqueue[pos] = ROOTList._RightChild          // Array
                        BABYqueue.add(ROOTList._RightChild)
                        print(ROOTList._RightChild.toString())
                        print(" ")
                    } else {
                        //BABYqueue[pos] = null
                        BABYqueue.add(null)
                        print("_ ")
                    }
                } else{ //если пустой то + 2 "_"
                    //BABYqueue[pos] = null        // Array
                    //pos++                       // Array
                    //BABYqueue[pos] = null      // Array
                    BABYqueue.add(null)
                    BABYqueue.add(null)
                    print("_ _ ")
                }
            }

            //NOWqueueList.clear() //worked when was MultitableList 

            NOWqueueList = BABYqueue.toList()          // equate
            //NOWqueueList = BABYqueue.clone()          // Array


            //println(NOWqueueList.joinToString(" "))   // вывожу готовый
            println()
            BABYqueue.clear()

        }
        //NOWqueueList.clear()
        BABYqueue.clear()

        return " end="
    }
}

fun main() {
    ...  there is a code here ...
}
```

I tried using Array, it still came out as with MultitableList

Comment: I'm a little surprised you consider any of these numbers large.  32MB is nothing.

Comment: Emm...  32 MB is data that was output.
And as a result, in order to output these paltry 32MB, the program will use up more than 200 MB of virtual memory

Comment: 200MB is also small.

Comment: man? ok and? what is my technical assignment? I need a maximum of 128 MB